# memory and cpu utilization of all running nodes

Tags: ros, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I would like to know if ros provides to capture the memory and cpu utilization of all the running node. Usually
rosnode all command will give the list of the all running node but not sure how to list the memory and cpu utilization of all the running nodes.does this facility provide  by the ros framework ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254689/memory-and-cpu-utilization-of-all-running-nodes/) by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2017-02-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In indigo, there is the [rosprofiler](http://wiki.ros.org/rosprofiler) package which provides this functionality.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on 2017-02-24**:
it doesn't work on kinetic due to compatibility issue . Could u suggest for kinetic any package.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a GUI-based tool [rqt_top](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_top) which shows CPU and memory consumption of running nodes:
[image: image description]

There is an official release, so you can install it via `sudo apt install ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-rqt-top`.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) with karma: 382 on 2018-06-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [apala_pramanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/114071/apala_pramanik/) on 2022-10-03**:
How can I launch rqt_top?